# Are 1 in 12 men color blind?

Tags: medical-science, biology, ophthalmology, colors

The *Colour Blind Awareness* [website](http://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/) claims that:

> Colour (color) blindness (colour vision deficiency, or CVD) **affects approximately 1 in 12 men (8%)** and 1 in 200 women in the world.

This claim appears in multiple websites, like [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-1327,00.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#cite_note-pmid21774112-1), and [Webexhibits](http://www.webexhibits.org/causesofcolor/2C.html). Wikipedia's color blindness [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Frequency_of_red-green_color_blindness_in_males_of_various_populations) even argues that in some population groups, like Russians and Arab Druzes, this number approaches 10%.

However, this number is just too high for me to believe. I've never met a color blind person in my life, or at least someone with a behaviour that would lead me to believe he's got a type of color vision deficiency. So, does 1 in 12 men suffer from a type of color blindness?

Comment: I know a few color-blind people, and unless they told me about it, I would never guess. My uncle is color-blind and I didn't notice it for 10 years of knowing him, until he mentioned it... 

Otherwise, keep in mind, color-blindness doesn't mean complete color-blindness (monochromatism), that's extremely rare. Usually it's simply an inability to distinguish certain (most often on the far right and left of spectrum), not all colors.

Comment: @sashkello Of course, I've done some research on the subject. It's shocking that there could be so much people I know that may have this and I'm not even aware.

Comment: Not only is a color vision deficiency not obvious to others it's sometimes not obvious to the people themselves!  My former employer did a color vision test for everyone that worked at the factory so the supervisors would know who couldn't fill in in the two jobs that required proper color vision.  20% failed and most had no idea they were color vision deficient in the first place.

Comment: The prevalence among male doctors in the United
Kingdom is also shown to be probably at about 8% which is same as
the estimated rate of 8% in general population referring to research here-http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1313448/pdf/10562750.pdf.

Comment: Part of the reason why red-green colour vision deficiency (the most common type) is so non-obvious is that red and green have very different *values*  (relative brightness), so affected people can very often (but not always) judge which is red and which is green based on how light or dark a colour appears. There are good sources describing this strategy; unfortunately I don't have time to put together a good answer today! I didn't realise a good friend of mine had red-green colourblindness for 10 years or so, until one day he asked for "the red book" while pointing at a very dark green book.

Comment: Wikipedia gives scientific references to back up its claims. What is it about those references that you don't believe?

Comment: I'm a man with red/green color deficiency and the only symptom I have noticed is inability to see the numbers in the color-blindness test book. I wouldn't even know I had it if I had not taken the test, and no one else would probably ever know.

Comment: @DJClayworth The number just resulted incredibly shocking for me.

Comment: @Gabe12 If you are shocked try to do the color-blind test to like 20+ of your friends (it takes 5 seconds: show them the test and ask which number is in it). Then find out the percentage of people you know that has color-blindness and see if it matches or not (note: using only family members isn't a good choice. Given that it's a genetic condition you'd probably find out either a lot more cases or a lot less cases. You need people from diverse families to obtani an average outcome with high probability).

Comment: [Most humans are color blind](http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/326976).

Comment: Archive of @CountIblis's link: http://web.archive.org/web/20160321084022/http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/326976 -- it's an article about the rare phenomenon of [tetrachromacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrachromacy#Humans).

Comment: Not knowing many people who are colour blind is not a strong piece of evidence. One of my children is and I didn't notice until he was a teenager.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Summary: *complete* colour blindness is very rare (less than 0.01%). What is common is various types of **deficiency in red-green colour vision in men**, which *is* around 8% (sex-linked because it's from an X-chromosome fault). This is based on a huge amount of evidence from accurate, widespread diagnostic testing.

You're unlikely to notice it in another person through normal social interaction because people with red-green colour blindness often learn from a young age how to estimate what's red, what's green and what's yellow/brown from contextual clues, experience, and data from other aspects of colour. It's rarely noticeable to another person outside of  situations that require accurate colour identification from hue alone.

---

With colour vision deficiency (CVD) tests so common, there's such an abundance of data on how common it is in various groups that it's actually quite tricky to pin down one authoritative source. This quick guide to the different types is based on [a table compiled in the book Colour Image and Video Enhancement by Springer press, 2015](https://books.google.com.sl/books?id=DIiQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&dq=Achromatopsia+Dichromacy,+Protanopia+men+women+population&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Achromatopsia%20Dichromacy%2C%20Protanopia%20men%20women%20population&f=false), based on Caucasian populations, which was the most completely labelled I could find. There's a huge amount of research on differences between racial groups, nationalities, occupations, etc, but from all the research I've seen there isn't any obvious pattern beyond that a distribution like this one is common:

| Type | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Complete colourblindness: "Monochromacy".** This combines monochromacy caused by having no cone cells at all ("achromatopsia"), as well as monochromacies with other causes. | 0.003% | 0.0001% |
| **One colour completely missing: "Dichromacy".** Functioning cone cells of one type not present in the retina: | - | - |
| No red: "protanopia" | **1.01%** | 0.02% |
| No green: "deuteranopia" | **1.27%** | 0.01% |
| No blue: "tritanopia" | 0.002% | 0.001% |
| **One colour shifted in sensitivity: "Anomalous trichromacy".** Causes a limited colour spectrum from one cone cell type: | - | - |
| Anomalous red: "protanomaly" | **1.08%** | 0.03% |
| Anomalous green: "deuteranomaly" | **4.63%** | 0.36% |
| Anomalous blue: "tritanomaly" | 0.0001% | 0.0001% |

You can see the vast majority of cases are of impaired red or green vision in men. These tend to be termed "red-green colour blindness" because in practical terms, the impact is very similar. The raw data from our optic nerve is converted into "[opponent processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opponent_process)": red opposed to green, blue opposed to yellow (where yellow is derived from the combined data of red and green cones), and light opposed to dark. Diagram from [Marc Green PhD](https://web.archive.org/web/20190110174546/http://www.visualexpert.com/FAQ/Part1/cfaqPart1.html):

[image: comes in an achromatic system (brightness) vs cones in a chromatic system (red-green, yellow-blue)]

Whichever it is a person is less able to use, between red and green light, the main practical impact is that they are less able to discriminate red from green, but can still discriminate colours using the other opponent process between yellow (red+green) and blue.

---

This adds up to the widely published figures of roughly 8% of men and well below 1% of women. One example of an authoratitive source publishing this summary is the American [National Eye Institute, who give the following](https://nei.nih.gov/health/color_blindness/facts_about):

> As many as 8 percent of men and 0.5 percent of women with Northern European ancestry have the common form of red-green color blindness.

They go on to explain the uneven sex distribution:

> Men are much more likely to be colorblind than women because the genes responsible for the most common, inherited color blindness are on the X chromosome. Males only have one X chromosome, while females have two X chromosomes. In females, a functional gene on only one of the X chromosomes is enough to compensate for the loss on the other. This kind of inheritance pattern is called X-linked, and primarily affects males. Inherited color blindness can be present at birth, begin in childhood, or not appear until the adult years.

---

**So why aren't we constantly meeting men who can't easily discriminate red from green?**

We are. It just doesn't come up in conversation.

[Red and green are very different in terms of relative brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Color_in_the_human_brain), with reds appearing darker than greens of similar intensity. Even when someone can't tell them apart by hue, there are often other clues: a dark splatter on grass near an accident will look like blood even if its hue appears the same as the surrounding grass.

Consider this example image using simulation filters, [taken from wearecolorblind.com](http://wearecolorblind.com/article/a-quick-introduction-to-color-blindness/):

[image: House from "Up" showing multicolor balloons in normal vision and green, purple, and white balloons in deuteran and protan vision]

It's easy to figure out how to classify the balloons in the CVD-simulated images into colourless, yellow, blue, and "other" (red, green or brown). You can even learn strategies for estimating whether a balloon is red or green  <sub>(this is something that, anecdotally, colour blind people often describe doing, sometimes assuming that everyone does this; and educators point to this to explain cases where children's colour-blindness goes unnoticed - but I can't find any non-anecdotal sources for this, so I'll just leave it as an aside for now).</sub>

It's possible to tell the balloons apart, and group them by similarity. The difficulty comes in *accurately naming* the colours. As [the author of colour-blindness.com puts it](http://www.color-blindness.com/2010/03/30/living-with-color-blindness/):

> We are colorblind. We can’t name colors. But we can handle most situations perfectly even if we don’t know correctly which color it really is.

So, unless you habitually get in situations where you need to accurately *name* the colour of an unfamiliar item, there's no reason why the CVD of your male companions would necessarily become apparent.

The above linked web page gives some examples of situations where it can be a problem:

> - A Sunburn can’t really be seen, only if the skin is almost glowing.
> - If meat is cooked can’t be told by its color.
> - There is no difference between the colors for vacant (green) and occupied (red).
> - Flowers and fruits can’t be that easily spotted sometimes.
> - And you can’t tell if a fruit or vegetable is ripe or not yet.
> - Every electrical device which uses LED lights to indicate something is a permanent source of annoyance.
> - Colored maps and graphics can sometimes be very hard to decipher.
> - ...matching colors, and especially, matching clothes.

Comment: Add to his list:  Color codes on things.  I can only read resistor color codes if I have a cheat card that I can hold up next to the resistor.  (And it has to be next to it, I need to be able to look at both at the same time and under the same lighting conditions.)  Even a cheat card won't let me read dot codes--the smaller the piece of color the harder it gets for me.  By the time it's a one-pixel line I can't tell pure red from pure green.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - One thing that irritates me is that some indicator lights switch between "red" and "green" when the indicator is changed.  The designers of these things could just as easily used red and blue.  They have the red/green indicators on the lockers in my gym and I have to "read" them just on brightness.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, have you ever tried "3D-glasses", where one lens is red and one is blue or green? That would make the red lights appear brighter in one eye and the green lights brighter in the other. (And yes, you *would* look silly, but who cares.) If it actually works for you, tinted contact lenses are an option.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I've never encountered lights I can't tell apart but I've seen plenty of "lights" on web pages that I can't tell apart.

Comment: @LorenPechtel For me it's not so much being unable to tell them apart (I usually can) as it is being unable to tell which one is the green one and which one is the red one. For example I used to have a battery charger whose light was red while charging and green when the battery was full. I often had no idea in which state it was in...

Comment: @DanielRHicks That's something I've never really thought of (to my knowledge I'm not colour-blind) but now that you mention it, I'm somewhat surprised by our regular colour conventions.  Red as bad and green as good is really common, but it seems like one of the most inconvenient combinations to use, since red and blue are so much less likely to cause issues.  I cant say I'm responsible for choosing the indicator light colour on anything, but if i ever find myself in that position I'll try to remember that.

Comment: @JMac says "*it seems like one of the most inconvenient combinations to use*".  Yes, but: 1) the human eye can't focus on blue light, so if knowing a specific position is important blue is a poor choice. Similarly, letters in blue light are difficult to read as they appear out of focus and blurry. 2) the blue LED wasn't available until quite recently (it's invention earned the 2014 Nobel prize), so any standards for electronic devices developed in the previous 40+ years could only use red and green LED (and yellow when the two are combined).

Comment: @RayButterworth - Blue LEDs have been available for at least 10 years.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, red and green LEDs have been available since the early 1970s.  Blue LEDs only started showing up in the late 1990s -- about a 30-year gap.

Comment: @Mark - As I said, blue LEDs have been available for over 10 years.